# Java Unit Testing with ActiveMQ 5.6.0

Tags: java, junit, activemq-classic

I have a series of JUnit tests for an application that I have been building, but when I run them against the 5.6.0 ActiveMQ library, it shows an error:

```
ERROR  checkSystemUsageLimits, Temporary Store limit is 50000 mb, whilst the temporary data directory: /path/to/temp/storage only has [less than 50,000] mb of usable space
```

It doesn't cause an error in the unit test, but I don't need 50GB of space for my unit tests. Is there a way that I can reduce the size of the requested size from 50GB to something less? If not, is there a way that I can easily suppress this error?

Edit: I should mention that I'm creating the connection to AMQ using the URL

```
vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false
```

So it's not using the activemq.xml config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your configuration to include a smaller size in

```
<systemUsage>
    <systemUsage>
        <tempUsage>
            <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
        </tempUsage>
    </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

default config (and links to schema and such) [here](http://activemq.apache.org/xml-configuration.html)

Comment: The ActiveMQ instance is created at runtime in memory using the URL "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false" so updating an activemq.xml file is not an option.

Comment: Actually, it should be an option.  Check http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html - "Configuring an Embedded Broker Using an External Config File".

Comment: I don't like using external files in unit tests because it defeats the purpose of a unit test being self-contained, but if there isn't another way, I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: You could look at the ActiveMQ Unit tests and how it creates BrokerService instance for each test and configures them.

Comment: i've certainly not done this myself, but you could try setting it up programmatically. Perhaps see http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html, creating a vm-based one vi URI and then manipulate the BrokerService (http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.6.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerService.html). As @Tim Bish says above, perhaps you can find some code in the AMQ unit tests (e.g, https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-core/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/EmbeddedBrokerTestSupport.java).

Comment: Yes, if you look through the ActiveMQ unit tests you'll find several examples of creating a BrokerService instance, and you can look for places that use the SystemUsage property to configure memory limits.